# Show contents of other folder based on subdomain htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

When i request:

```
subdomain1.domain.com

i want to show the contents of /httpdocs/subdomain1/
```

When i request

```
subdomain2.domain.com

i want to show the contents of /httpdocs/subdomain2/
```

I want to keep subdomain2.domain.com without redirect

i have a Wildcard on my Plesk, i just don´t know how to set up htaccess

i tried this so far, but is not working

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.domain\.com$ 
RewriteRule ^ http://subdomain.domain.com/%1%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `http://` in target otherwise it will do a full redirect not just silent rewrite as you want.

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.)([^.]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

`RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$` will ensure we rewrite only once.