# .htaccess - Need to change root folder based off the wildcard subdomain

Tags: .htaccess

Hope you all can help.

I have wildcard subdomains for a site like so...

test1.domain.com
test2.domain.com

Both open /subdomain/index.php

Here is what I need to do. In /subdomain there are 2 folders

/subdomain/test1

```
in test1 is an img folder /subdomain/test1/img
```

/subdomain/test2

```
in test2 is an img folder /subdomain/test2/img
```

I would like to open this URL https://test1.domain.com/img/test.png to see the image I can open https://test1.domain.com/test1/img/test.png and it loads the image but I would like the to not show the test1 after the domain name.

So opening https://test1.domain.com/ would be loading https://test1.domain.com/test1/

I have checked so many posts, I found redirects and what not but that's not what I need.

Thanks.

Comment: I finally found the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42699337/show-contents-of-other-folder-based-on-subdomain-htaccess

Comment: Answer here for anyone else looking https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42699337/show-contents-of-other-folder-based-on-subdomain-htaccess

Comment: Sure. Easiest always is to use separate `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folders for separate http hosts. If you are unable to configure that (for example if you do not have access to the central configuration), then you can rewrite requests to a folder based on a string you pick from the requested host.